# Temporal join on Temporary views

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Can the temporal join be achieved on Temporary views?

I’m using Flink SQL to create 2 tables using `kafka` and `upsert-kafka` connectors respectively. Applying some transformation on these tables and then creating temporary views. The final query joins both these two temporary views. Here, I'm able to apply a simple equi-join, but when tried for temporal join, the client throws the below exception:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Temporal Table Join requires primary key in versioned table, but no primary key can be found. The physical plan is:
```

The initial table I created has primary key but when the temporary view is created after the transformations, there is no primary key in the view.

Can we enable primary key for a temporary view? Can the temporal joins be performed on temporary views?